# increment last number in given string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck in one javascript code...

I want to increment the number in below string -

i.e:

```
invoice[1][ap_details][1][description]
invoice[1][ap_details][2][description]
invoice[1][ap_details][3][description]
invoice[1][ap_details][4][description]
invoice[1][ap_details][5][description]

[description] - This could be any text.
```

I am using below code -

```
var strNewName  = $( this ).attr( 'name' ).replace( /\[\d+\]/g, function( strName ) {
    strName = strName.replace( /[\[\]']+/g, '' );
    var intNumber = parseInt( strName ) + 1;
    return '[' + intNumber + ']';
});
$( this ).attr( 'name', strNewName );
```

above code replace both the numbers in string.

Original string - `invoice[1][ap_details][1][description]` 
after running above script - `invoice[2][ap_details][2][description]`

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I have one question: why?  Why are you not using two nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.attr()` , `RegExp` `/(\d+)(?=\]\[)/` to match digit followed by closing bracket `"]"` folowwed by opening bracket `"["`

```js
$("input").attr("name" , function(i, attr) {
  return attr.replace(/(\d+)(?=\]\[)/, function(match) {
    return Number(match) + 1
  })
});
console.log($("input").attr("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input name="invoice[1]details[1][header]" />
```

Comment: I tried above suggested but it increments first number and not last. I want to increment last number only. btn thank for you help :)

Comment: @Abhijit _"tried above suggested but it increments first number and not last."_  Increments last number, here; at stacksnippets, jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/abwx95ku/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to increment the details number then you should be more specific in your regex: `.replace( /details\[\d+\]/g, ....`

Example:

```
'invoice[1].details[1]'.replace(/details\[(\d+)\]/g, function(match, num) {
    return "details["+ (+num + 1) +"]";
});
```

Comment: I have update my question. Any help would be appreciated.